# Any way to display Vimperator's UI elements from top instead bottom?

Tags: vimperator

I would like to have displayed Vimperator command line and possibly Buffers and everything else from top, instead from bottom, is there any way how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done, http://vimperator.org/help/vimperator/gui.xhtml#status-line mentions settings and commands for each GUI element and statusbar has none. You probably should contact the developers and ask to add the option of statusbar position at page top.